# SQL- Select just on row

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

As you shown in the image that have a lot of addressTypeID with the same Application id and ValidTo Date rows.

sometimes need to use the `AddressTypeID` as a condition on the returned column.

I need to make the query that will get the validTo in condition with AddressType and some details from application table which connect to the applicationID:

```
SELECT APPLICATION_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
,MAIL_DATE = (SELECT VALIDTO FROM ADDRESS WHERE ADDRESSTYPEID = 1)
```

i need the output be just one row that contain that:

```
applicationid - firstname - lastname - validto
38  - John   - smith   - 2020-12-31 00:00:00.000
39  - Math   - Will    - 2015-09-23 00:00:00.000
```

without make the row be repeated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?>

Comment: dbms sql server

Comment: You could use `max(validto)`.

Comment: sometimes will use the validto when the addressType=2

Comment: Attached screenshot with data doesn't include [firstname] and [lastname] columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
SELECT APPLICATION_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
,MAIL_DATE = (SELECT MAX(VALIDTO) FROM ADDRESS WHERE ADDRESSTYPEID = 1)
```

Or

```
SELECT APPLICATION_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
,MAIL_DATE = (SELECT Top 1 VALIDTO FROM ADDRESS WHERE ADDRESSTYPEID = 1 Order by ValidTo desc)
```

Comment: the validTo will get : 9999-09-09 00:00:00.000

Comment: Max will get value from your data.

Comment: i'm try to do that and doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

JOINs usually perform better than correlated subqueries.

If `application_id` and `addresstypeid` combination is unique,then simply:

```
SELECT t1.APPLICATION_ID,
  t1.FIRST_NAME,
  t1.LAST_NAME,
  t2.validto
FROM first_table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS t2
ON t1.application_id = t2.application_id
AND t2.addresstypeid = 1;
```

If not, you can do something like:

```
SELECT t1.APPLICATION_ID,
  t1.FIRST_NAME,
  t1.LAST_NAME,
  t2.validto mail_date
FROM first_table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT application_id,
    MAX(validto) validto
  FROM ADDRESS
  WHERE addresstypeid = 1
  GROUP BY application_id
  ) t2
ON t1.application_id = t2.application_id;
```

Comment: max(validto) will get just the first row  but sometimes will try to get the second row

Comment: If the combination of applicationid and addresstypeid is unique, you can use the first query and provide which addresstypeid you need.

Comment: If they're not unique, use second query. If say you want to select 2nd row, use addresstypeid = 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM Address WHERE ValidTo IS NOT NULL

OR

SELECT APPLICATION_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, Row FROM
(
    SELECT APPLICATION_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,
           ROW_NUMBER() 
           OVER(PARTITION BY Application_ID ORDER BY ValidTo) AS Row
    FROM Address
) tmp
WHERE tmp.Row = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`max(case when addTypeID =1 then addValidTo else '' end)`

Comment: Code-only answers are not very helpful. Please add some explanation of how your code solves OP's problem; this will help everyone, especially the less experienced who come across this question.